# How to debug 'no production for X' in lbnf / bnfc grammar?

Tags: grammar, bnfc

when playing around with lbnf/bnfc, in some cases I would like it to optionally allow for the plural form. However it always says 'no production for 'Plural' appearing in rule' and and I do not get why.
Relevant line below. SomeOther and SomeToken are basically strings.

`HeadAuthors. Authors::= "AUTHOR" [Plural] ":" SomeOther SomeToken ;`

`Plural. Plural::= "S" ;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would skip the list, and make Plural into a rule like this

```
rules Plural ::= "S" | ;
```

For documentation about the `rules` macro, see https://bnfc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lbnf.html#rules.

If you want to keep the list, then you need to give a separator or terminator for Plural, see here https://bnfc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lbnf.html#terminator, otherwise it doesn't become a list. You can just write

```
terminator Plural "" ;
```